# Django filtering on foreign key properties, difference between explicit and implicit foreign key property naming

Tags: django, django-1.9

Suppose I have two `model`s -

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_id=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    a_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
    a=models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to filter `B` objects which belong to a particular `a_id`. I can either do this -

```
B.objects.filter(a=a_id)
```

or

```
B.objects.filter(a__a_id=a_id)
```

Is there any difference between the two, in terms of efficiency, speed or functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B.objects.filter(a=a_id)` is much more efficient because it simply filters the values of `B.a` and avoids joining table `A` altogether, while `B.objects.filter(a__a_id=a_id)` requires joining table `A` by `a_id` and then filtering `a_id` with `a`.

Comment: Sorry for this follow up question which comes in way too late. I printed out the queries for both the operations, and they seem to be equivalent. `SELECT "app_B"."id", "app_B"."b_name" from "app_B" WHERE "app_B"."a_id" = 1 LIMIT 21`

Comment: I see. Apparently in recent versions Django has done optimizations over such usage. I'm fairly sure that they were not producing the same SQL queries in the early days (when I checked it myself a long time ago I was using Django 1.4).

Comment: I see. Thank you.